# How to understand the trimmed mean in Scipy

Tags: python, mean, trim, scipy.stats

I can't explain the behaviour of `trim_mean()` in `Scipy.stats`.

I learned that trimmed mean calculates the average of a series of numbers after discarding given parts of a probability distribution.

In the following example, I got the result as **6.1111**

```
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 30, 4, 4, 5]
trim_percentage = 0.05  # Trim 5% from each end

result = trim_mean(sorted(data), trim_percentage)
print(f"result = {result}")
```

**result = 6.111111111111111**

However, I expect that 1 and 30 will be cut out, because they fall under the 5 percentile and above the 95 percentile.

When I do it manually:

```
import numpy as np

data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 30, 4, 4, 5]
p5, p95 = np.percentile(data, [5, 95])
print(f"The 5th percentile = {p5}\nThe 95th percentile = {p95}")

trim_average = np.mean(list(filter(lambda x: x if p5 < x < p95 else 0, data)))
print(f"trimmed average = {trim_average}")
```

I got this:

**The 5th percentile = 1.4**

**The 95th percentile = 19.999999999999993**

**trimmed average = 3.4285714285714284**

Does this mean the `trim_mean()` treats each number separately and assumes a ***uniform distribution***? The `proportiontocut` is explained as "Fraction to cut off of both tails of the distribution".  But why it behaves like if the distribution were not considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing in the documentation should be more precise: it cuts a fraction of the *observations* in your sample. You have 9 values, and 5% of 9 values is 0.45 values. However, it can't cut off a fraction of a value. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html) states that it

> Slices off less if proportion results in a non-integer slice index

So in your case, zero values are cut from both ends before taking the mean.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 30, 4, 4, 5]
np.mean(x)  # 6.111111111111111
stats.trim_mean(x, 0.05)  # 6.111111111111111
```

You can verify that the result changes when `proportiontocut` exceeds `1/len(data)`:

```py
from scipy import stats
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 30, 4, 4, 5]
p = 1 / len(x)
eps = 1e-15
stats.trim_mean(x, p-eps)  # 6.111111111111111
stats.trim_mean(x, p+eps)  # 3.4285714285714284
```

This behavior appears to be consistent with the description of a trimmed mean on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean), at least:

> This number of points to be discarded is usually given as a percentage of the total number of points, but may also be given as a fixed number of points... For example, given a set of 8 points, trimming by 12.5% would discard the minimum and maximum value in the sample: the smallest and largest values, and would compute the mean of the remaining 6 points.

SciPy does not have a function that trims based on percentiles (of which there are [many conventions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24588#issuecomment-1866805858)). For that, you'd need to write your own function, or perhaps there is such a function in another library.

Please consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Documentation&projects=&template=Documentation.yml&title=DOC%3A+%3CPlease+write+a+comprehensive+title+after+the+%27DOC%3A+%27+prefix%3E) about improving the documentation.

Comment: What I was confused about the trim_mean() [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html) was the term "distribution". Clearly, cutting off 5% each side of the tails from a normal distribution is not the same as doing it on an uniform distribution. Based on the Wikipedia definition you provided, there is no **_"distribution"_** considered, only a percentage of each number in the total number of points. Therefore, regardless the distribution of the numbers, treating them as an uniform distribution.

Comment: Please let us know if https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/19788 (PR to improve the documentation ot `trim_mean`) would have helped.

Comment: Thank you Matt! I think "a specified fraction of extreme values" is helpful for me. It also aligns with Wikipedia.
Appreciate your detailed explanation and quick response.